# Database corrupt after restore and upgrade on another instance

Tags: sql-server, corruption, dbcc-checkdb

We have SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.2789) and SQL Server 2014 (12.0.2000) instances. There is a process of backup on SQL Server 2008 R2 and restore to SQL Server 2014.

Everything was going fine, until today. The database gets correctly backed up (without errors or warnings), restored, and upgraded. `DBCC CHECKDB` on the source is ok, but `DBCC CHECKDB` fails on the target just after the restore.

I would raise a ticket to Microsoft, if it wasn't the most confidential db in the house ;)

Details:

1. Both machines are virtual boxes; source is on a decent traditional SAN, target resides on our full flash array beast. Both are serving other servers with no consistency errors. The backup is saved locally as with checksum *xxxxxx.tmp*, then transferred over network and when the transfer ends without error, file is renamed to *\xxxxxx.bak*. This file gets restored on the target server.
2. Yes, a fresh backup helped, it was our first try. But why the corrupted one can restore on SQL Server 2008 R2 without corruption, but not on 2014?
3. 'Exact' errors were couple of following in two tables"

   > Object ID .., index ID 1, partition ID .., alloc unit ID ..(type In-row data). Page (1:..) is missing a reference from previous page (1:..). Possible chain linkage problem.
   >
   > Object ID .., index ID 8, partition ID .., alloc unit ID ..(type In-row data), page (1:1116376). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 2057 and -4.`

Bad sectors are probably not the cause. The data resides on a reliable SAN with lots of other systems which aren't complaining about data inconsistency. If 2014 was on sick storage, why would the fresh one restore smoothly?

It is a regular daily backup/restore process, this happens just once in a 'long period'.

Comment: Can you ask hardware team to check the storage hosting SQL Server 2014. How did you move backup file. If you moved it over network was it Zipped and moved or it was just moved like that

Comment: Can you create a new db on the 2008 R2 box (use the AdventureWorks script), back it up and restore on the 2014 box, and run DBCC ? Sounds like you hit some bad sectors on 2014's storage. Can you ask your sysadmins to provide another LUN or set of disks ?

Comment: Are there any SQL Server memory dump-files on the source or target servers? We had SQL Server database-corruption happening randomly. Only sign was the memory dump files (in SQL Servers log folder). Eventually we replaced the server-hardware, eventhough all hardware diag came back clean. After that, the corruption disappered